# How to insert data in a table with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, foreign-keys

I want to insert data in table `Article` which has a foreign key to table `Categorie`.

I created a form with TextBoxes and I put the foreign key in a bounded ComboBox to `Categorie` table. This is the code I use:

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection();
    con3.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GestStock.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    con3.Open();

    SqlCommand insertCommande1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Article] (CodeArticle, LibArticle, IdCategorie, Quantite, StockActuel, StockMinimum, PrixAchat, DateAchat, NumeroFacture)" +
              "VALUES(@CodeArticle, @LibArticle, @IdCategorie, @Quantite, @StockActuel, @StockMinimum, @PrixAchat, @DateAchat, @NumeroFacture)", con3);

    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeArticle", codeArticleTextBox1.Text);
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LibArticle", libArticleTextBox.Text);
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCategorie",idCategorieComboBox.Text);

    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantite", Convert.ToInt32(quantiteTextBox1.Text));
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockActuel", Convert.ToInt32(stockActuelTextBox1.Text));
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockMinimum", Convert.ToInt32(stockMinimumTextBox1.Text));
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrixAchat", Convert.ToInt32(prixAchatTextBox1.Text));
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAchat", Convert.ToDateTime(dateAchatDateTimePicker1.Text));
    insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroFacture", numeroFactureTextBox.Text);

    insertCommande1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("L'article est ajouté avec succées");
    con3.Close();
}
```

But when I execute this code the `Article` is added successfully but when I exit the application and re-run it I get this error message:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values that violate type constraints not null, unique, or foreign key.

I know that it is caused by this

```
insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCategorie", idCategorieComboBox.Text);
```

So my question is how to do insert query in a correct way??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please translate your error message to English?

Comment: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values that violate type constraints not null, unique, or foreign key.

Comment: You have to insert such value to `IdCategorie` that exists in table to which FK is built.

Comment: Don't write query in page, try to use strored procedure, SP provide the solution for you..

Comment: How to use stored procedure?? can you give link please??

Comment: Does idCategorieComboBox.Text containt the ID? Maybe you mean idCategorieComboBox.Value?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051986/data-insert-using-input-output-stored-procedure

Comment: idCategorieComboBox.Text contains LibCategorie because it is the DisplayMember of the bounded combobox (idCategorie is the ValueMember), there is no preperty idCategorieComboBox.Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
insertCommande1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCategorie",  idCategorieComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
```